# How to get Symfony profiler in Behat Test

Tags: php, symfony, selenium, testing, behat

I was wondering on how to get the Symfony profiler within a behat test? I've read the offical [docs](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/using_the_profiler_with_minkbundle.html) about it but I keep getting the error

"You need to tag the scenario with @mink:symfony2".

I think this is a configuration problem:

**behat.yml**

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
       - FeatureContext:
           em: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
           router: '@router'
           tokenStorage: '@security.token_storage'
           encoder: '@security.password_encoder'
           session: '@session'

  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_test.php"
      goutte: ~
      selenium2:
        wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
      sessions:
        default:
          symfony2: ~
```

**config_test.yml**

```
framework:
  test: ~
  session:
    storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
  profiler:
    collect: true

web_profiler:
  toolbar: false
  intercept_redirects: false

swiftmailer:
  disable_delivery: true
```

My feature context extends MinkContext and I am using Selenium for driving my tests that require javascript. I've tagged the feature that I want to execute the following:

```
@mink:symfony2
@javascript
Scenario: User send mail
# ...
```

Comment: Tagging a scenario with `@javascript` makes that you cannot use the Symfony driver, so tagging it with `@mink:symfony2` and `@javascript` in the same time is useless. The Symfony driver doesn't support javascript.

Comment: So how to access the profiler and at the same time use javascript?

Comment: Profiles are stored on the filesystem. You could read them with Symfony classes. Have a look at how it's done in https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Client.php#L69-L73 . There's also a way to read a profile by its id, which can be read from the response headers.

Comment: thanks a lot, will have a look at it